# Why do we need "potential” for amortized analysis?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, amortized-analysis

In [the current version](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Potential_method&oldid=713008203) as of [the Wikipedia article “Potential method”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_method), the amortized cost of each operation is defined as the following
$$
T_{\mathrm{amortized}}(o) = T_{\mathrm{actual}}(o) + C \cdot (\Phi(S_{\mathrm{after}}) - \Phi(S_{\mathrm{before}})),
$$

and the total amortized cost is 
$$ \begin{align*}
T_{\mathrm{amortized}}(O) &= \sum_i (T_{\mathrm{actual}}(o_i) + C \cdot (\Phi(S_{i+1}) - \Phi(S_{i}))) \\ &= T_{\mathrm{actual}}(O) + C \cdot (\Phi(S_{\mathrm{final}}) - \Phi(S_{\mathrm{initial}})).
\end{align*} $$

I understand the formulas and understand $T_{\mathrm{amortized}}$ is an upper bound on $T_{\mathrm{actual}}$ if the initial potential is zero. And I think I understand the basic examples like "binary counter", "two stack FIFO", etc. However, I am puzzled this:

> The actual cost is part of the formula.

I might be wrong but it looks like the actual cost is a known quantity. **If we already know the actual cost, why do we need to add the "potential" to get an upper bound**? It looks useless to me. Can anyone help give an example in which such "potential analysis" is useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is unfortunately sometimes the case, Wikipedia is doing a terrible job of explaining what amortized analysis actually is.

The idea of amortized analysis is that while operations may have a bad worst case cost, their *average* cost could be much lower. Average cost means different things in different circumstances. In amortized analysis, here is what it means:

> Suppose that you have a data structure supporting operations $O_1,\ldots,O_r$. We say that these operations have *amortized cost* $c_1,\ldots,c_r$ if the cost of the sequence $O_{i_1},\ldots,O_{i_n}$ of operations is at most
>   $$
> c_{i_1} + \cdots + c_{i_n}.
> $$

This definition is a bit simplistic, since sometimes the amortized cost depends on other auxiliary parameters such as the overall number of operations or the number of operations of a specific type.

The *potential method* is one way of carrying out amortized analysis, that is, of proving that the operations in a certain data structure have some amortized cost. Stated differently, if you want to prove that the amortized cost of $O_1,\ldots,O_r$ is $c_1,\ldots,c_r$, then one of the techniques is the potential method. There are other techniques as well.

How does the potential method work? You define a potential function $\Phi$ on the state of the data structure. The potential function must be always non-negative, and for the initial data structure it must be zero. You then prove that if at state $S_{\text{before}}$ you execute operation $O_i$ which leads to state $S_{\text{after}}$, then the cost $T_{\text{actual}}$ of the operation satisfies
$$
T_{\text{actual}} \leq c_i + \Phi(S_{\text{before}}) - \Phi(S_{\text{after}}).
$$
Given that this holds for all $i$, consider a sequence of operations $O_{i_1},\ldots,O_{i_n}$, and denote the corresponding states of the data structure by $S_0,\ldots,S_n$. The upper bound on $T_{\text{actual}}$ implies that the total cost of these operations is at most
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{t=1}^n [c_{i_t} + \Phi(S_{t-1}) - \Phi(S_t)] &= \sum_{t=1}^n c_{i_t} + \sum_{t=1}^n [\Phi(S_{t-1}) - \Phi(S_t)] \\ &=
\sum_{t=1}^n c_{i_t} + \Phi(S_0) - \Phi(S_n) \\ &=
\sum_{t=1}^n c_{i_t} - \Phi(S_n) \\ &\leq
\sum_{t=1}^n c_{i_t},
\end{align*}
$$
which was to be proven.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Once this Q&A has settled a bit, please improve the Wikipedia article! (But to address your opening remark, I'd expect explaining what amortized analysis actually is to be in the [article on amortized analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis), and the article on the potential method to assume that the basics of amortized analysis are known.)